# Finding root of file and read in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to read a file into database in prolog with code below:

```
open('C:/Files/text.txt', read, S)
```

it read perfectly but i have to use my pl into another computer and directory can be different
for example if change the open code with

```
open('text.txt',read,S)
```

even if the my pl file and txt is in the root (C:/Files/text.txt) it fails to read.

Is there any correction to read the txt. whatever root pl and txt in it, just same folder is matter?

Comment: Which version of SWI-Prolog are you using (`--version`)? Strangely enough, in `SWI-Prolog version 5.10.4 for i386` I can only get `open(…)` to work without the third value, although the documentation says it is a three-valued predicate. Otherwise I get `No permission to modify static_procedure \`open/3'`. (Apparently I have not been doing Prolog for too long.)

Comment: @PointedEars That sounds like an error you'd get for trying to *define* `open/3` rather than invoke it. I suspect you have a syntax error somewhere, or are trying this on a `:|` prompt instead of the `?-` prompt.

Comment: @DanielLyons Thank you for the reminder. Using `open(…)` LHS instead of RHS was the problem. On the RHS I am getting `open/3: source_sink \`…' does not exist (No such file or directory)` which is probably the OP's problem.

Comment: @PointedEars Post the code. Prolog usually isn't thought of as possessing a left- or right-hand side since `=/2` means "unify" and not "assign."

Comment: @DanielLyons Why, `pred(_) :- open('include.pl', read, _).` instead of `open('include.pl', read, _).` gives that error, of course (now that you reminded me). The problem appears to be that the relative path is resolved from the *working directory*, not the directory of the knowledge base. Which I assume is the OP's problem. I can see no solution yet but to change the working directory *before* invoking `swipl`(1), as `working_directory/2` will still be filesystem-dependent. But perhaps you have a better idea.

Comment: I think you're correct. Also I would probably say head and body instead of left and right there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the predicates absolute_file_name/[2,3] to see 
how a relative file name is resolved. For example I get:

```
?- absolute_file_name('text.txt', X, [mode(read)]).
X = 'c:/users/user/documents/prolog/text.txt'.
```

Usually the working directory is used to resolve a relative
file name from the top-level. You can access and modify the 
working directory as follows:

```
/* get the wd */
?- working_directory(X, X).
X = 'c:/users/user/documents/prolog/'.

/* set the wd */
?- working_directory(_, 'c:/users/user/desktop').
true.

?- absolute_file_name('text.txt', X, [mode(read)]).
X = 'c:/users/user/desktop/text.txt'
```

The consult predicates use a different rule during consult, 
they resolve relative to the file that is currently consulted.